# Error in using WebClient.DownloadString in asp.net vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sendmail

I am using `WebClient.DownloadString` method in `vb.net`to convert asp.net page to string after that I send this string by email.
by I got this error from the server

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

Unfortunately, no more details about the error. what is the possible problem ?

### edit:

error in the following line of code :

```
Dim str As String = client.DownloadString(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/GFOPortalA/isd/ViewForm.aspx?ISD_FRM_NO=" + Session("ISD_ReqId"))
```

Comment: Can you debug and see on which line the error is happening?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know hot debug :(

Comment: Open the project in Visual studio and hit F5

Comment: This is not a error with sending email.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal this is in what then ?

Answer (score 0):

in your web.config, make sure you have :

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```